# A accesses B's shared resources, B cannot access A?

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

Two Ubuntu 14.04 machines, A & B with wired links via local router, are configured identically as far as I can manage. Their smb.conf files, identical except for share path names, declare:

```
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    wins support = yes
    name resolve order = wins bcast host
```

All media are declared in smb.conf as:

```
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

and all media are configured as shareable and "Allow others to create and delete...".

Using Files, A can see WORKGROUP and access B's shared resources but **B cannot see A's WORKGROUP shares** nor any other machine shares on WORKGROUP. Windows machines on the same network can see shared resources on both machines (but not access them-- passwords not accepted??). All firewalls, A, B and local router, are off.

A possible clue: on B, `ping A` does not find the correct local IP address for A and pings an old address for A from a previous network configuration; on A, `ping B` works correctly.  arp tables on A and B are essentially similar; B has a correct local address for A.  Where is B getting it's ping IP address for the local machine named A?

Is there some checklist of network configuration I can use to figure out what is going on here? Sharing on both machines worked well on 12.04 and were recently switched to 14.04 (B was upgraded but A was a fresh install) at the same time as new router installation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that A had no Samba users configured whereas B did. Thus the user of A was known to B and automatically accepted but the B user was unknown to A. In fact, A had no known users (maybe, because it was a new install of 14.04, whereas B was an upgrade) so A neither showed it's shared resources nor allowed access. Users are not configured in smb.conf so I missed this asymmetry between the two machines.

This was most easily fixed using the Samba Server Configuration GUI; the **Preferences** menu includes a **Samba Users** item and window to add new users with a network password. This adds the user name in `/etc/samba/smbusers`, a file which didn't exist on B before.

I believe the user name and possibly the password as well should be the same on each reciprocally shared machine-- at least, it works that way for me. I'm sure there is a way to have a single network user file rather than one on each machine-- I'll figure that out some day.